# "Configuration file modified [...] What would you like to do about it ?" prompt does not allow me to continue while upgrading to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I got the following prompt when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04:

```
Configuration file '/etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?
```

I chose `D` to see the difference before I decided. Now the program will not allow me to continue.

Looks like the cache is still locked but it moved me back to the prompt. I got:

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock. It is held by process 2743 (dpkg)... 234s
```

Any ideas?

Comment: At the prompt, type "exit" to close the shell and return to the parent upgrade process.

Answer (score -1):

Try running the following commands:

```
sudo killall -9 dpkg
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And if you have not a scanner configured say `y` to the question.
If you have a scanner keep current file.